# How to make the width of the background of a menu with width limited to 100%?

Tags: css, background-size

[Click this image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxH36.png)

The width of the above menu is limited to 1200px.
Note that the width of the entire site is limited to 1200px.
But I want to set the full size of the yellow background when I press the menu.
What should I do?

"background-size : cover;" or "background-size : 100% auto" dose not works.

Comment: please share code to investigate. looks like you have a container there that sets the width for yellow bar

Comment: I'm guessing that an parent/ancestor element is limiting the width of the menu. Please share your code and create a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the box that contain the background to 100vw of width;